# Can a path be closed?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading up on a research paper involving graph theory with which I was never exposed to before. 
Looking up some elementary text, there is a mentioned of 'Path'.

> Definition: Path
>
> A Walk W written as a sequence of distinct vertices is a path. 
>   This means
>
> $W=v_{0}v_{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot v_{k}$

But for a path to be closed, it is required that

$W=v_{0}v_{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot v_{0}$

Am I misunderstanding anything?

An illumination of my doubts would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, it may differ from one textbook to another, probably read more here, hopefully it answers your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory) .

Comment: I don't understand the $\forall i \not = j$ in the above definition.

Comment: @Gribouillis Ignore that. I'll make the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the usage in graph theory is that a path is never closed (all vertices, including the first and last, must be distinct), and the equivalent closed version is called a cycle. This differs from walks or trails, which can be closed, and for which there is no special word for the closed version (it is just called a "closed walk" or "closed trail").